# CSS - content hiding behind header bar

Tags: html, css

I am generating my header, sidenav and content like this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm pad">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li *ngFor="let module of modules">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/navbar',module.id]" routerLinkActive="active">
        {{module.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['dashboard']" routerLinkActive="active">
        Dashboard
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['test-page']" routerLinkActive="active">
        Test
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Page renders like attached image. Header bar position is set to fixed and hence the some part of "content" div is hiding behind the header bar. How to resolve this. I know if "content" div will be set to something like `"margin-top:Xpx"` will solve the issue. However when viewed in mobile mode this does  not work and content again goes behind the header bar. Is there a way so that in any viewport the content of `content div` should always show below the header bar when the header bar position is set to `fixed`.

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing questions that best enable the community to provide helpful assistance.  In this case, it would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] in a snippet that reproduced the problem.  Also, in a question tagged CSS, I would consider it particularly important your CSS be included in the question.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `position:fixed;` - use `position:sticky; top:0;` instead.

[Sticky positioning | position - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)

Comment: Thanks @richard deeming. That worked.